# JS injections vs program in window.onload

Tags: javascript, onload, code-injection

I'm writing a web game in PHP+JS and I'm really affraid of JS injections.
Is it possible to inject script, of which all variables and functions are closed in window.onload?
like:

```
window.onload = function(){
     //all stuff here
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be possible to inject script at all... Why are you afraid of it? Escape and encode everything carefully and you're fine.

Comment: If you're still afraid, you could implement [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives), but I hate it, because it's still broken in every single browser that 'supports' it.

Comment: Of course prod versions will be uglified and completely unreadable, but I'm still affraid. Does any threat exist?

Comment: Readabiity is completely irrelevant. If you don't encode your input/output correctly, a threat definitely exists. If you're careful, no * injection is possible (but still 1500 other ways to be hacked of course).

Comment: What I mean is is there a way to change variables or call functions closed on onload? If it comes to JS-PHP bridge, I'm already protecting my script.

Comment: The client can change anything and everything. The moment I download your code, it's mine to do with whatever I want. With these days' devtools and extensions it's easy. That's just 1 person changing code for 1 person though, so no problem. All the rest comes from escaping and encoding. If you're asking "does a function wrapper protect me": no, it does not.

Comment: You can learn a bit more about XSS atacks here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)